# How to map screen location with 3-D terrian coordinates in XNA 3.1

Tags: xna

I am facing a problem while working in XNA 3.1 framework.
Actually I created a terrain model from DEM file. Terrain model is having a X,Y,Z coordinates. The terrain is created in the lower half of the screen. In xna domain 0,0 is the centre of the screen. 
My problem is that, I want to identify the terrain coordinates when user click on the screen (using mouse). In screen view 0,0 is the left top most corner. I am getting difficulty in maping screen coordinates with my terrain coordinates and vice versa.

Is any one has faced the similar problem or let me suggest any solution for this any pointer would be helpful for me.

Thanks 
Adee

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called "picking", and there is an infinity of resources about that on the net. In short, it consists of:

- generating a ray in 3D space that goes from front to back of your view frustum, using the mouse coordinates as X,Y
- apply the reverse transformation of your view-projection matrix to get this vector in world space
- test for intersection between this vector and each polygon of your terrain
- use z-order to choose the closest intersecting polygon

See [XNA Picking Tutorial](http://ghoshehsoft.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/xna-picking-tutorial-part-i/) for an in-depth explanation. Or just google "picking 3D".